# Scope of JButtons confusion

Tags: java, swing, events, scope, actionlistener

Ok so I fixed the scope of the JButtons, i put them inside the body of the class instead of the body of the method. So, why am I getting this error?

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

```
                          at SalutonFrame.main(SalutonFrame.java:78)
```

Here is my source code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SalutonFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public JButton careerNew = new JButton("Begin your programming career!");
    careerNew.addActionListener(this);
    JTextField responseText = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField.addActionListener(this);
    public SalutonFrame() {
        super("Saluton Mondo!");
        setLookAndFeel();
        setSize(1000, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 10);
        setLayout(flow);
        //set row 1
            JLabel responseLabel = new JLabel("YourResponse:", JLabel.RIGHT);
            JComboBox choiceResponse = new JComboBox();
            choiceResponse.addItem("Yes");
            choiceResponse.addItem("No, I'm an idiot");
            add(careerNew);
            add(choiceResponse);
            add(responseLabel);
            add(responseText);
        //set row 2
        JPanel badCareer = new JPanel();
            JButton startBad = new JButton("Start a life of misery");
            JLabel startBadLabel = new JLabel("Your Response, Not that it Matters though:", JLabel.RIGHT);
            JTextField startBadText = new JTextField (20);
            JComboBox startBadCombo = new JComboBox();
            startBadCombo.addItem("You dont have a choice");
            startBadCombo.addItem("You dont have a choice");
            startBadCombo.addItem("You dont have a choice");
            startBadCombo.addItem("You dont have a choice");
            startBadCombo.addItem("You dont have a choice");
            startBadCombo.addItem("You dont have a choice");
            startBadCombo.addItem("You dont have a choice");
            startBadCombo.addItem("You dont have a choice");
            startBadCombo.addItem("You dont have a choice");
            startBadCombo.addItem("You dont have a choice");
            startBadCombo.addItem("Dafuq u still looking?");
            badCareer.add(startBad);
            badCareer.add(startBadLabel);
            badCareer.add(startBadCombo);
            badCareer.add(startBadText);
        add(badCareer);




        setVisible(true);
    }
    // sets User-generated event from button careerNew
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            Object source = event.getSource();
            if (source.equals (careerNew)) {
            CareerGood career = new CareerGood();
            }
            else if (source == responseText) {
                JLabel fart = new JLabel("Idiot");

            }
        }



    private void setLookAndFeel() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                    "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        }
        catch (Exception exc) {


        }
    }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SalutonFrame frame = new SalutonFrame();        }
    }
```

Help?

Comment: Is this all of your code? You cannot have instructions in the body of your class! And you should definitely use an IDE like Eclispe...

Comment: Lol @Samy yes i do have Eclipse. and i am sorry, i am just beginning java. where should i have the instructions?

Comment: Well so it should be obvious to you that something's wrong (underlined in red...) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Move these two instructions

```
careerNew.addActionListener(this);

JTextField.addActionListener(this);
```

after the call to `super` in you constructor.

Here's a complete version:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class SalutonFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public JButton careerNew = new JButton("Begin your programming career!");
    JTextField responseText = new JTextField(20);

    public SalutonFrame() {
        super("Saluton Mondo!");
        careerNew.addActionListener(this);
        responseText.addActionListener(this);
        setLookAndFeel();
        setSize(1000, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 10);
        setLayout(flow);
        // set row 1
        JLabel responseLabel = new JLabel("YourResponse:", JLabel.RIGHT);
        JComboBox choiceResponse = new JComboBox();
        choiceResponse.addItem("Yes");
        choiceResponse.addItem("No, I'm an idiot");
        add(careerNew);
        add(choiceResponse);
        add(responseLabel);
        add(responseText);
        // set row 2
        JPanel badCareer = new JPanel();
        JButton startBad = new JButton("Start a life of misery");
        JLabel startBadLabel = new JLabel("Your Response, Not that it Matters though:", JLabel.RIGHT);
        JTextField startBadText = new JTextField(20);
        JComboBox startBadCombo = new JComboBox();
        startBadCombo.addItem("You dont have a choice");
        startBadCombo.addItem("You dont have a choice");
        startBadCombo.addItem("You dont have a choice");
        startBadCombo.addItem("You dont have a choice");
        startBadCombo.addItem("You dont have a choice");
        startBadCombo.addItem("You dont have a choice");
        startBadCombo.addItem("You dont have a choice");
        startBadCombo.addItem("You dont have a choice");
        startBadCombo.addItem("You dont have a choice");
        startBadCombo.addItem("You dont have a choice");
        startBadCombo.addItem("Dafuq u still looking?");
        badCareer.add(startBad);
        badCareer.add(startBadLabel);
        badCareer.add(startBadCombo);
        badCareer.add(startBadText);
        add(badCareer);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    // sets User-generated event from button careerNew
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Object source = event.getSource();
        if (source.equals(careerNew)) {
            CareerGood career = new CareerGood();
        } else if (source == responseText) {
            JLabel fart = new JLabel("Idiot");

        }
    }

    private void setLookAndFeel() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Exception exc) {

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SalutonFrame frame = new SalutonFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: >Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 careerNew cannot be resolved to a variable
 responseText cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Friend, there's a lot of problems in your code... Line 9 I believe you wnant it to be `responseText.addActionListener(this)`, and again move these instructions (line 7 and 9) in the body of your constructor, after the call to `super`. Try my code, you shoud at least get something running.